# JRuby Rails3 application session timeout running in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails

If you have a session timeout in rails using the :expire_after in session_store.rb

```
AppRails3::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
   key: '_App_Rails3_session', 
   :expire_after => 20.minutes
```

and in Tomcat you set session-timeout in the web.xml.

Which one will be used? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part will expire the cookie session store.

The tomcat one will take care of the java servlet session store.

So, the answer is both.

Comment: I'm testing it now in Tomcat, and it seems to me that the session-timeout from the web.xml is ignored.

Comment: And indeed, both are used. In my case, the one having least number of minutes will force re-login.